# How to Display different API results in the same place when clicking on the links given in navbar?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is it possible to render the different components on the same place when clicked on the links?

I have a `SideNav` and a `TopNav` Components in my page inside the `APP` component. What I want to do is to insert a Thrind component in the middle of the page that displays the different results when clicked on different links and buttons.

My App Component is like

```
import {SideNav} from "./SideNav";
import {TopNav} from "./TopNav";
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={'container'}>
                <SideNav />
                <TopNav />
                <div className={'content'}>
                    Content will be rendered here on clicking the link but how?
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

I want to display different components inside ***container*** class.
What can be done to do this?

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

class SideNav extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
                <div className={"sidenav"}>
                    <Router>
                    <Link href="#">About</Link>
                    <Link href="#">Services</Link>
                    <Link href="#">Clients</Link>
                    <Link href="#">Contact</Link>
                    </Router>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want the links to render different components on the same place by clicking them. for example , If i click `Home` I want to display Home than that of the existing content in the middle of page. What is the procedure.

**My `Home` Component just displays `Hello World` as of now**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your content with the router and not the navigation components. Like this:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Router>
                <div className={"container"}>
                    <SideNav />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/">
                            Some home content
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/services">Some Services content</Route>
                        <Route path="/clients">Some Clients content</Route>
                        <Route path="/about">
                            <About />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/contact">Some Contact content</Route>
                    </Switch>
                    <div className={"content"}>
                        Content will be rendered here on clicking the link but how?
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And then in your nav components you just use the links:

```
class SideNav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"sidenav"}>
                <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                <Link to="/services">Services</Link>
                <Link to="/clients">Clients</Link>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I made you a working sandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-feistel-w59vm).

Comment: ```Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>```. It is showing this error now

Comment: Did you put your router component -outside- all the others? You will notice in my example that the `Link` s are in the `SideNav` which is it self rendered -inside- the `Router` in the main app.